# How to set Microphone vs Microphone Boost in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, audio, microphone

I have a Windows 7 Desktop that I want to use a mic. I connected the mic to the pink input jack (mic in). But the volume is too soft. When I enter the properties menu, I see something like this:

[image]

What is the difference between the Microphone and Microphone Boost? How do I determine the optimal setting?

In addition, there is another Control Panel tool which is related to microphone setup. It makes me read a sentence "Peter dictates to his computer... blah blah blah". After that, it says it did not hear anything even though I clearly see the volume changes as I read. I read it again and it then told me my microphone is now set up! What does it really do?

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a technical answer for you, but I can share my experience when testing different combinations of the two. I've found that the Boost level does a good job of making the microphone sound very close to me, when I move it further away - whereas the Volume becomes audibly 'distant' and quiet when it's moved away, and the alternative to turn it up, which literally picks up all the noise it senses, including background fuzz. Put the Volume too high and voices will begin to sound 'tinny'.

You can turn the Volume down then, but move the Boost up, and you will get a louder voice without that effect. Bear in mind that Boost will still pick up background noise to some extent, so trial and error is what's needed.

Comment: I find this answer puzzling for several reasons. (1) When you say "boost does a good job of making the microphone sound very close to me, when I move it further away" do you mean that your voice sounds louder over the mic to the other person? When you say "move it further away" do you mean move the mic away from your mouth as you speak or do you mean moving the slider?

Comment: (2) When you say "Put the Volume too high and voices will begin to sound 'tinny'." what volume do you mean exactly? Do you mean the speaker output volume on your PC? In other words, if you increase the output volume from your speakers then it makes your own voice over the mic sound tinier? Is that it?